# ProgressBar not appearing in Android app

Tags: android

I am developing an application that controls an Arduino Uno can gets data from the sensors connected to it's analog input pins.

I want to display their values in a horizontal bar all together under each others.

My activity_main.xml is as below:

```
<ScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tempLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:weightSum="100">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tempLabel"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                            android:text="Temperature = " />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tempValue"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="50"
                            android:text="20 °C" />

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/lightLayout"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="100"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lightLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:text="Light: "
                            android:layout_weight="15"/>

                        <ProgressBar
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:id="@+id/lightBar"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="75"
                            android:progress="50"
                            android:max="100"
                            android:minHeight="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/lightValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="10"
                            android:text="50%"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/waterLayout"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="100"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/waterLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:text="Water:  "
                            android:layout_weight="15"/>

                        <ProgressBar
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:id="@+id/waterBar"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:layout_weight="75"
                            android:progress="50"
                            android:max="100"
                            android:minHeight="10dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/waterValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="50%"
                            android:layout_weight="10"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/gasLayout"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:weightSum="100"
                        android:padding="10dp">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/gasLabel"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                            android:layout_gravity="end"
                            android:text="Gas: "
                            android:layout_weight="15"/>

                        <ProgressBar
                            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="10dp"
                            android:padding="5dp"
                            android:id="@+id/gasBar"
                            android:layout_weight="75"
                            android:progress="50" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/gasValue"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="10"
                            android:text="50%"/>

                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </ScrollView>
```

The problem is that the bars are not shown when I run the app on my mobile.

How can I fix this issue?

Here's a snapshot that show the app and in this render the bars appear normally:
[Uno Remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSEkf.jpg)

Comment: You have set `android:layout_height="10dp"`. Have you tried increasing its height?

Comment: Yes of course but it didn't help

Comment: I've tried setting these also from my onCreate():
lightBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.lightBar);
        lightBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        waterBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.waterBar);
        waterBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        gasBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.gasBar);
        gasBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

Comment: @Mahmoud Mahdi: I have used ur layout and the progress bar are displayed at my end. Can u post ur output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set height of progress bar 10dp, and padding of it 5dp. It means paddingTop = 5dp and paddingBottom = 5dp, not enough space to see progress bar.

You should increase progress bar height a little, such as 20dp. Hope to help you!